Keyframes are not moving
I have downloaded a walking animation, I want the animation to start after some frames like after 10 frames because I want the cloth simulation to be stabilized before the walking animation starts. I tried to drag the keyframes forward to play after frame 10 but the animation still starts from frame 1. The default animation length is 120 frames no matter how much I drag the keyframes it still starts from frame 1 and ends at frame 120. I opened the summary in the timeline, and the animation data added more keyframes in between when I moved the keyframes but after frame 120 the keyframes seemed to be empty. 

May be because your end frame is only set to 120 frames. Try adjusting it to a higher number.

I've already tried that still doesn't works.

So you are unable to move the keyframes even if your end frame extends beyond 120 frames?

Yes the animation still starts from frame 0 even if I extends the end frame beyond 120 frames I guess there is something locked in the animation data.

That's really weird. So you can't move the keyframes at all away from the beginning of the timeline?

No, I can't able to drag those frames.

Is there any chance the keyframes are locked? I know the screenshot doesn't show that, but what about sub-categories inside the character layers?
